# VirtualHost on Apache is not directing correctly

Tags: apache-2.2, xampp, virtualhost

I am running Xampp for a dev server on Windows 7.

my windows 7 hosts file @ `(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)` has this...

```
127.0.0.1 www.testing.com testing.com localhost
```

My Apache http-vhosts.conf 
*`(E:\Server\apache\conf\extra\http-vhosts.conf)`*

file has this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "E:/Server/htdocs/myframework"
ServerName testing.com
ServerAlias www.testing.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "E:/Server/htdocs/"
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Now my problem is when I go to `testing.com`, `www.testing.com`, or `localhost` in the browser, it ***ALWAYS*** loads the files from `E:/Server/htdocs/myframework` so the real problem is when I go to `localhost` it should load files from `E:/Server/htdocs/` instead of from `E:/Server/htdocs/myframework`

I am at a loss here, can someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're missing a `NameVirtualHost` directive, forcing all requests to be serviced by the first listener on that port to load.

Look around for it in the config - you'll want `NameVirtualHost *:80`, if it's not there.

Comment: This NameVirtualHost should be in the same file as my virtualhost listed above?

Comment: I got it now I added it above the virtualhosts and all is working, thank you I would of never figured that out